# Swift KingFisher - How to display picture from google storage

Tags: swift, google-cloud-storage, kingfisher

I use Kingfisher with swift 3, I displayed my pictures hosted in a directory on my apache server. I just changed for Google Cloud Plateform, and my picture are hosted now in Google Cloud Storage, but I cannot retrieve my picture anymore, the link seems to be correct because when I use it in a browser, I can see the picture (but the url change in the adress bar)

[Link Google storage of my picture](https://storage.cloud.google.com/dirpicturefortest/53141097041434918.jpg) :

https://storage.cloud.google.com/dirpicturefortest/53141097041434918.jpg

```
@IBOutlet var profilPictureCollection: [UIImageView]!

let image = self.profilPictureCollection[picture.rank]
let url = URL(string: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/dirpicturefortest/53141097041434918.jpg")
image.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

The UIImageView stays empty

Comment: There's a HTTP 302 for storage.cloud.google.com, you see it if you do `curl -IL "https://storage.cloud.google.com/dirpicturefortest/53141097041434918.jpg"` in the Terminal. I suppose that Kingfisher doesn't know what to do with it - maybe you could open an issue about this on their GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric. So I found the problem, in fact I tried to open the link on my browser where I was authenticated! I didn't add public permission on my google bucket! Now it works.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks for the feedback.